# Как при выводе на печать использовать запятую в качестве десятичной точки

Tags: python, float, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так, чтобы вывод float(нецелого числа) был с запятой, а не точкой?
Такой код:

```
a=float(int(input()))
print(a)
```

возвращает:    `1.14`
а мне нужно:   `1,14`

Как это можно реализовать

Comment: Используй функцию format

Comment: Если вам нужно просто отобразить на печати запятую вместо точки - то вам eri уже дал совет. Если же вы хотите, чтобы у вас вещественное число использовало запятую как разделитель целой и дробной части, то вам нужно менять локаль. Мало того, что это лишние движения, это еще и очень _вредно_. Крайне не советую этого делать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если данный формат нужен только для вывода на печать, то можно привести ваше значения "a" к типу string и заменить "." на "," используя `replace()`:

```
a = float(int(input()))
a = str(a).replace(".", ",")
```

Либо, как уже писали, поменять локаль, чего делать также не рекомендую.

Comment: @V S: *«...поменять локаль»* - Не поменять, и **использовать**. В этом разница.

Comment: @MarianD ваша правда, редко с этим сталкиваюсь. Спасибо за уточнение!

Answer (score 4):

**Короткий ответ**

Примените стандартный модуль [locale](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/locale.html):

```
print(locale.str(a))          # выводит 1,14
```

---

**Долгий ответ:**

1. Ваш код *никогда не может вывести* `1.14`, потому что ваша команда

   ```
   a=float(int(input()))
   ```

   ожидает только **целые** числа - в противном случае выводит ошибку

   > ```
   > ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.14'
   > ```

   Вы вероятно хотели

   ```
   a = float(input())
   ```
2. Для вывода *локализованных версий* значений предназначен модуль [locale](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/locale.html);
   для перевода числа `a` типа `float` применяется **его** функция `str()`:

   ```
   locale.str(a)         # 1,14   (или 1.14 в другой, например английской локализации)
   ```
3. Значит, вся ваша программа может быть такой:

   ```
   import locale

   a = float(input())
   print(locale.str(a))
   ```

---

4. Когда бы у вас было неправильно установлена среда (например на английскую) - что очень невероятно — примените после импорта команду

   ```
   locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "")        # для операционной системы
   ```

   или (например)

   ```
   locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "ru_RU")
   ```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, очень подробно все объяснили, однако я использую это лишь в одной строчке кода, поэтому из за этого не хотелось бы импортировать целую библиотеку. А так же int я добавил из за того, что библиотека PIL

Comment: '''image = Image.open(r'')
a=float(input())
font = ImageFont.truetype(r'C:\Windows\Fonts\arialbd.ttf', 70)
drawer = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
drawer.text((1324, 86), a, font=font, fill='red')''' такой код дает ошибку

Comment: @АА, спокойно импортируйте «целую» библиотеку (и может быть ещё 20 других) - это ничего не стоит, импортируются только имена.

Comment: @АА, мне кажется, что вы хотите создать отдельный вопрос. Так создайте, но полноценный, а не в форме комментария.